# If a value exists in a row, return the same value in the following x cells

Tags: excel, function, indexing, match

If there exists a row value in the top table, I would like to return the same value to the corresponding bottom table - and the following 11 cells.  [Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bnk7q.png):

[image: Screenshot]

Any ideas?

Comment: Edit: If a value exist in a row, return the same value in the following x CELLS

Comment: You can edit the question using the [edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/33551162/edit) link.

Comment: @ergonaut: return the value that was found in the top table. If you take a look at the screenshot, you see an example - return the value from the orange cell to all the green cells. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can use a formula like this:

```
=IF(COUNTIF($B1:$I1,A$10)>0,B1,)
```